# MQTTnet client certification

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mqtt

I have the following bug, when trying to connect to a mosquitto broker on a server using the following options, i get the following error about the Private Key, but i am using the server,crt to authenticate which has no private key assigned.

**Code:**

```
    var serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2("ca.crt");
    Debug.WriteLine("+++++" + serverCertificate.HasPrivateKey);

    var mqttClient = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttClient();

    // Create TCP based options using the builder.
    var options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
        .WithClientId("foo")
        .WithTcpServer("192.168.1.126", 8883)
        .WithCredentials("myusername", "mypassword")
        //.WithTls(true)
        .WithTls(true, false, false, serverCertificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert))
        .WithCleanSession()
        .WithProtocolVersion(MqttProtocolVersion.V311)
        .WithKeepAlivePeriod(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
        .WithCommunicationTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
        .Build();

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    var connect = await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(options);
```

**Error**

[image]

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should probably generate a client cert instead then.

Comment: @Cheesebaron i just added client certs but M2MQTT does not find the private key, althought the **serverCertificate.HasPrivateKey** becomes true, the **ConnectAsync** does not find it.

Answer (score 0):

1. i stored my cert in `/data/user/0/com.companyname.name/files`
2. use this command to create a pfx file 
   `openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.pfx`
   use the `.pfx` instead of `.crt`

read the `.pfx` from the local files as `byte[]` use it as a cert